# Lookup routed target controller in Play-Framework Filter

Tags: playframework

I want to track the calls by type in a playframework filter (2.1.2).

```
object WhichEndpointCallMetricsFilter extends Filter {

  def apply(next: RequestHeader => Result)(rh: RequestHeader) = {

    rh.path match {
     case x if x startsWith "/devices" => Metrics.registry.meter(MetricRegistry.name("http.requests.devices." + rh.method)).mark()
     case x if x startsWith "/messages" => Metrics.registry.meter(MetricRegistry.name("http.requests.ping." + rh.method)).mark()
     case _ => Metrics.registry.meter(MetricRegistry.name("http.requests.UNKNOWN." + rh.method)).mark()
     }

    next(rh)
  }
```

}

What I don't like at all is that I am duplicating paths (like "/devices"), which are already defined in the 'routes' file. Is there a way to lookup the target controller-class inside a filter?

I am sure there is a play-like helper like:

```
Routes.lookupControllerClass(request):Controller
```